# valid parentheses including characters

Tags: python, parentheses

I have to check "valid parenthesis" but I have characters in my strings, and I allways obtain False. Can anyone help me to do it?
This is my code:

```
str1 = '((a))[]'

def isValid(test_str):  
    if len(test_str)%2 != 0:
        return False
    par_dict = {'(':')','{':'}','[':']'}
    stack = []
    for char in str1:
        if char in par_dict.keys(): 
            stack.append(char)
        else:
          if stack == []:
              return False
        open_brac = stack.pop()
        if char != par_dict[open_brac]:
          return False
    return stack == []

isValid(str1)
```

Comment: Why are you testing that the length is even?  What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The first if condition will not work, your string has many different characters, they could be parenthesis, brackets, braces or even any other character, so we may have something valid like `(a)` which is of odd length and **valid**, but your code would return `False`, we should remove it!

After the `else`, we should check if the character is really some type of bracket or any other character, what if we had this string `()a`, this is a valid *balanced* string, so shouldn't we really be testing if the character is some type of bracket or just any other bracket? If it's just a normal character, we could skip it using the `continue` keyword.

Now lastly, popping the element from the stack and comparing if it's the correct pair of brackets should be done in the else right?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comments that the first if condition is incorrect and needs to be removed.

I debugged your code carefully, and have rearranged it to produce the following version that appears to be working. Some logic was in the wrong place and needed to be moved into the "inner" nested if statement.

I changed the logic of the else statement in the outer-if block, to check if a character is ")", "]", "}". Any character that it is not a bracket is ignored in this code. Here's the implementation with a couple of test cases.

```
def isValid(test_str):  
    par_dict = {'(':')','{':'}','[':']'}
    stack = []
    for char in test_str:
        if char in par_dict.keys(): 
            stack.append(char)
        elif char in par_dict.values():
          if stack == []:
              return False
          open_brac = stack.pop()
          if char != par_dict[open_brac]:
            return False
    return stack == []

print(isValid('(())'))
print(isValid('((a))'))
print(isValid('((a)))'))
print(isValid('((a)))[]'))
print(isValid('((a))[]'))
print(isValid('(())[]'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Cogi. It works; I think that ignore any character that is not a bracket is a very interesting solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you defined a second variable for `O(1)` validation of the closing brackets as well (since the problem could be extended to support a lot more characters in which iterating over all the values in the dictionary would be a bottleneck):

```
OPENING_BRACKETS = {'[', '(', '{'}  # Better to use a frozenset.
CLOSING_BRACKETS_TO_OPENING_BRACKETS = {']': '[', ')': '(', '}': '{'}  # Better to use a immutabledict.

def isValid(s: str) -> bool:
    if not s:
        return True
    stack = []
    for ch in s:
        if ch in OPENING_BRACKETS:
            stack.append(ch)
        elif ch in CLOSING_BRACKETS_TO_OPENING_BRACKETS:
            if not stack or stack[-1] != CLOSING_BRACKETS_TO_OPENING_BRACKETS[ch]:
                return False
            stack.pop()
    return not stack
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

Add the expected closing bracket to the stack when you find an opening one. Then just check any occuring closing bracket on whether it fits the current expected closing bracket from the stack.

```
def isValid(test_str):
    o_to_c_dict = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']'}
    stack = []
    for char in test_str:
        if char in o_to_c_dict:
            stack.append(o_to_c_dict[char])
        elif char in o_to_c_dict.values():
            if not stack:
                return False
            if char != stack.pop():
                return False
    return not stack
```

Comment: You don't want to add closing brackets to the stack, nor does your code do so.

Comment: True @Thierry Lathuille, edited it to include that case

Answer (score -1):

The first mistake I see is your first if condition. Actually, when you authorize any character to be included in your input string, that's impossible to reject string based on their length.

Comment: This might be a comment, but can't be considered an answer according to SO standards. Note that if you are typing that on your phone, you should pay attention to the automatic correction - or switch to an English keyboard...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Will try to improve myself. Damn autocorrect, though